# Mapping through array in React with nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a school project, I am making a dashboard where I want to visualize some data. I've already got it so far that I can load the data into the front end which is react.

Now I want to get certain values ​​from the array. But since it's a fairly large array, I'm not exactly sure how to loop through this.

The data looks like this:
[image]

I want to have the _value for each object so that I can eventually load it into a area chart from rechart.

The code for the areachart:

```
<AreaChart
    width={1550}
    height={400}
    data={this.getMachineData()}
    margin={{
        top: 10,
        right: 30,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    }}
>
<CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
<XAxis dataKey="name" />
<YAxis dataKey="_table" />
<Tooltip />
<Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stackId="1" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
<Area type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stackId="1" stroke="#82ca9d" fill="#82ca9d" />
<Area type="monotone" dataKey="amt" stackId="1" stroke="#ffc658" fill="#ffc658" />
<Legend />
    <Bar dataKey="_value" fill="#8884d8" />
    <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
</AreaChart>
```

I have already made a method but it is not implemented yet:

```
getMachineData(data) {
    console.log(data)
    const result = data.map((innerArray) => {
        console.log(innerArray)
        // Map over the inner array
        return innerArray.map((item) => {
            // Return an object with only the properties you need
            return ({
                time: item._time,
                value: item._value
            });
        });
    })
    console.log(result)
    return result;
};
```

I was thinking of looping through the object myself with the .map function but since they are objects within objects I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You're nearly there - `this.state.machineData.map(number => number._value)`

Comment: dont forgot to return the result of the `map` function too

Comment: @WillJenkins I've changed the function, so I can store the values from _value in an array,  but i ve got undefined returned.

Comment: return `values` from `getMachineData`

Comment: @WillJenkins Yes I get that but I want to check the values ​​first by logging them to console so I can see them and there they are already undifined

Comment: so you're probably calling `getMachineData` before `state.machineData` is defined. Can you add complete code for the component?

Comment: @WillJenkins I have changed the function now I get the values from _value. Now i only need to add the _time value so i have the (_time, _value) that can be visualized in the chart.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by objects within objects. What I see in the above image is an array (with 816 objects) inside an array. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by objects within objects. What I see in the above image is an array (with 816 objects) inside an array. So a simpler way using the map function would be:

```js
const data = [
  [
    { _time: 1, _value: 2 },
    { _time: 3, _value: 4 },
    { _time: 5, _value: 6 },
    { _time: 7, _value: 8 },
  ]
]

const results = []

// Map over the outer array
data.map((innerArray) => {
  // Map over the inner array
 return innerArray.map((item) => {
    // Return an object with only the properties you need
    results.push({
      time: item._time,
      value: item._value
    });
  });
})

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response! I've updated my function. I got the error message that innerArray.map is not a function?

Comment: @TomvandenBogaart do `console.log(typeof innerArray)` to confirm that it is indeed an array. You can only `map` over arrays. With your error, that means it's not an array.

Comment: @Justsolarry You are right, because i've declared the array machineData: [''] in the beginning.

Comment: @TomvandenBogaart Then you're using the wrong/incorrect variable. You may `console.log(innerArray)` to see the contents. In your code, you have `const data = this.state.machineData;` you can `console.log` that and see what values you are getting.

Comment: I changed my code to simplified is some bit but now it wont go in the  const result = data.map((innerArray) => { the console.log(data) is the same output as in the image

Comment: @Ajay I have updated my code and now i cannot see the console.log(result) because the innerArray.map is not working?